# Excel 2010 Remove duplicates conditionally

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have data as noted in example below and I need to remove duplicate values retaining the latest updated value and remove the data that is in bold and italics

Time Delivered  Time Difference Name    Order #

4/1/2011 21:25  9:04:23 Hilton, Kevin M.    f0000865

***4/1/2011 13:31   1:10:23 Hilton, Kevin M.    f0000865***

4/1/2011 19:30  7:09:57 Hilton, Kevin M.    f0000864

***4/1/2011 13:31   1:10:57 Hilton, Kevin M.    f0000864***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your data by Time Delivered descending (newest first), then remove duplicates from the table using Order# as the only criterion.  That should work because the Remove Duplicates function keeps the first unique record from the top and removes duplicates that follow.